# React - saving state to local storage

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

We are working on a program where some part of the state has to be persistent. Localstorage seems to be the perfect solution for many reasons, except for the part where we cannot get it to work.

At first the local storage always seemed to update on step behind the rest of the program, as if its was being supplied an older state. 
We tried - after consulting some tips from blogs - the following approach

We update the localstorage with the callback of the 'setState' call.

```
this.setState(
    {selection: this.state.selection.concat(shop_item) },
    () => {
      this.saveToLocal();
    }
);
```

The 'SaveToLocal' function is as follows:

```
saveToLocal() {
       const local = this.state.favourites;
       this.localStorage.setItem(‘saveFavorites’, JSON.stringify(local));
   }
```

Yet this code does not seem to supply any value to localstorage at all. Does anyone have an idea of what we are doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show how you initialize `this.localStorage`?

Comment: Oh my god. That was it. 
We removed the 'this' and the function worked again. 

I will upvote your response, whilst sitting in the corner and wearing my hat of shame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You should use only `localStorage` not `this.localStorage`.**

Also, I would remove your arrow function on the callback of setState as you do not pass any parameters to `this.saveLocal()`.

It should be more readable in this way:

```
this.setState(
  { selection: this.state.selection.concat(shop_item) },
  this.saveToLocal
);
```